# Exercício com do while no prompt de comando utilizando Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

sou novo na programação e preciso de ajuda com um exercício da graduação. Estou tentando fazer um calculador de IMC (índice de massa corporal) no Javascript utilizando prompt integrando HTML. Porém, o exercício pede que exista um "Loop" nesse pedido/prompt até que o usuário escolha quando ele deseja sair do loop (pelo prompt). Exemplo: Se o usuário digitar 1, fazer o cálculo, exibiu na tela e quiser saber novamente ele continua apertando 1. Tentei fazer com while, do while, utilizando switch mas não consegui pegar a lógica ainda. Vou inserir o código que fiz "parcialmente".

```
alert("Cálculo do IMC!!!");

do {

    const opcao = prompt("Digite qual opção você deseja: 1 para calcular IMC e 2 para SAIR");

    switch(opcao) {
        case '1':
            var peso = prompt("Digite seu peso em kg: ");
            var altura = prompt("Digite sua altura em m: ");    
            var imc = peso / (altura * altura);

            if(imc < 18.5)
                alert('O cálculo do seu IMC deu ' + imc + ' indicando que você está abaixo do peso');
            else if(imc >= 18.5 || imc < 24.9)
                alert('O cálculo do seu IMC deu ' + imc + ' indicando que você está normal');
            else if (imc >= 25 || imc < 25.9)
                alert('O cálculo do seu IMC deu ' + imc + ' indicando que você está em sobrepeso');
            else if (imc >= 30 || imc < 34.9)
                alert('O cálculo do seu IMC deu ' + imc + ' indicando que você está em Obesidade I');
            else if (imc >= 35 || imc < 39.9)
                alert('O cálculo do seu IMC deu ' + imc + ' indicando que você está em Obesidade II');
            else if (imc >= 40)
                alert('O cálculo do seu IMC deu ' + imc + ' indicando que você está em Obesidade III');
            break;
        case '2':
            alert("Saindo do programa!!!");
            break;
        default:
            alert('Digite uma altura ou peso válidos!');
            break;
    }
} while (opcao != '2')
```

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045), [ask] e faça o nosso [tour]. PS: Existem quase uma centena de publicações no site sobre [imc em javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+imc).

Comment: no `default`, ou seja, quando não escolher uma das opções esperadas, deveria usar um `continue` no lugar de `break` para voltar ao início

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seu código está fazendo a declaração da variável opcao dentro do escopo da estrutura do-while, o que faz com que ela só possa ser acessada dentro da própria estrutura, gerando um erro ao executar a comparação no while, uma forma de resolver isso é realizando a declaração da variável fora da estrutura e apenas atribuindo seu valor dentro dela.

Outra coisa que você pode mudar é o "default" da estrutura switch, pois já que ela está fazendo referência a variável opcao não faz sentido dizer que o usuário digitou altura ou peso inválido já que ele apenas digitou uma opção.

E no IF você está usando o operador ||(OU), que ao receber uma de suas comparações verdadeiras acaba executando o código, nesse exemplo seu o ideal seria o operador &&(E) já que você deseja que o valor esteja entre dois números, exemplo:

```
valor > 10 || valor < 15 // retornará verdadeiro pra qualquer valor, afinal os valores que não são maiores que 10 são menores que 15
valor > 10 && valor < 15 // retornará verdadeiro apenas se o valor for maior que 10 e menor que 15
```

ainda não pude testar, mas refiz o seu código da seguinte forma:

```
alert("Cálculo do IMC!!!");

let opcao;

do {

    opcao = prompt("Digite qual opção você deseja: 1 para calcular IMC e 2 para SAIR");

    switch(opcao) {
        case '1':
            var peso = prompt("Digite seu peso em kg: ");
            var altura = prompt("Digite sua altura em m: ");    
            var imc = peso / (altura * altura);

            if(imc < 18.5)
                alert('O cálculo do seu IMC deu ' + imc + ' indicando que você está abaixo do peso');
            else if(imc >= 18.5 && imc < 24.9)
                alert('O cálculo do seu IMC deu ' + imc + ' indicando que você está normal');
            else if (imc >= 25 && imc < 25.9)
                alert('O cálculo do seu IMC deu ' + imc + ' indicando que você está em sobrepeso');
            else if (imc >= 30 && imc < 34.9)
               alert('O cálculo do seu IMC deu ' + imc + ' indicando que você está em Obesidade I');
            else if (imc >= 35 && imc < 39.9)
                alert('O cálculo do seu IMC deu ' + imc + ' indicando que você está em Obesidade II');
            else
                alert('O cálculo do seu IMC deu ' + imc + ' indicando que você está em Obesidade III');
            break;
        case '2':
            alert("Saindo do programa!!!");
            break;
        default:
            alert('Digite uma opção válida !');
            break;
    }
} while (opcao != '2')
```